# Power supply and dimmer/pot specs needed for LED A19 bulb in DIY desk lamp

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm making a desk lamp using a single dimmable A19 7w LED. My questions:

1. What kind of dimmer/potentiometer can I use?
2. Can I simply run an extension-type cord from the A19 bulb socket/base into a 110V wall outlet, or is there something special (e.g., power supply) needed?
3. Is there a newb-friendly resource for learning how to do these relatively simple electronics projects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

an a19 has an e26 base, so its designed to operate on line voltage.  so you need to have a dimmable led bulb with an e26 base.  dimming will have to be done with a proper ul listed dimmer switch in an appropriate metal device box.  you cannot use a potentiometer for this.  you do not need a power supply if the bulb is designed for line voltage.  you can find hundred of videos on this sort of stuff on youtube or you can try www.make.com